# In youtube how to hide title text and light gradient when in full screen mode

Tags: css, youtube, hide, gradient, title

In youtube how to hide title text and gradient when in full screen mode
To be able to see data under title text and gradient

Try installing custom css extension
Ex
[https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylebot-web/](https://stackoverflow.com)
[https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/qb-custom-css/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search](https://stackoverflow.com)

navigate to youtube url and paste below code in the custom css window

```
.ytp-title{
display:none;
}

.ytp-gradient-top{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: try to change `display: none;` to `display: none !important;`